# How do I disable the note when sending an email?

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to disable the creation of a "log note" when I send an email using the `send_mail()` method of mail.template?

Basically what I'm doing is sending an email to all team members every time a ticket is opened in the helpdesk. the problem is that in the ticket itself, it creates as many log notes for me as there are emails I send.

How can I disable the creation of log notes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue which you are facing so my solution :

```
        mail_id = template_valuess.with_context(
            ctx).send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
        if mail_id:
            mail_obj = self.env['mail.mail'].sudo().browse(mail_id)
            mail_message_id = mail_obj.mail_message_id
            mail_message_id.res_id = False
```

It worked for me as i unlinked the res_id.

**Note: If someone has better option, please add as i'm looking for alternative too.**

Comment: Thanks, but i have found another solution, using in values auto_delete = True, it seems to work

Comment: Yes this'll work too but in my case i need emails for record(s). Also auto_delete will not works if outgoing server fails to send email (that might not be a valid case).

Comment: You are right, I will try to adopt both solutions, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution add `auto_delete:True` on template's value